# static sub-domain forwarding where url remains unchanged

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, redirect

Running an IIS7 server, I can't figure out how to set up a static subdomain url redirect.

I want this url:

```
subdomain.mysite.com
```

to forward to:

```
mysite.com/index.php?query=string
```

but the url still looks like

```
subdomain.mysite.com
```

in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set up a wildcard domain in the DNS Manager on the windows server.  [Here](http://dirk.net/2008/05/28/wildcard-host-header-binding-and-subdomains-with-iis7/) is a decent workaround for this.